# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : how to access a variable's value that is defined in Program.cs from a controller?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application & I created a variable in my `Program.cs` file and assigned it a random UUID value.

I then use that variable as part of several endpoint routing patterns, also defined in my `Program.cs` file.

My question is, if I need to access that same variable and its UUID value from within my controller file, how do I go about doing that?

I've tried researching how to create global variables & accessing them between .NET files - but none of those techniques seem to work for ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Here is a code snippet from my `Program.cs` file that shows the created variable (`uuid1`) and how it is used in some of the endpoints route patterns I would like to be able to access the variable `uuid1` from within my `HomeController`. Thanks in advance.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    Guid uuidi = Guid.NewGuid();
    string uuid1 = uuidi.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("UUID: " + uuid1);
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "views",
        pattern: uuid1,
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "views",
        pattern: "/" + uuid1 + "/exit/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Submitted" });
                
    endpoints.MapGet("/uuid", async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(uuid1);
    });
```

Comment: IMHO `services.Configure<MyConfigClass>(c => c.uuidi = .... )'` then you can inject `IOptions<MyConfigClass>` without needing to know how the value was configured.

Answer (score 4):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to write a class which store the value and register it as Singleton service.

Then you could use it inside the controller.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Class:

```
public class ChannelOptions
{
    public string? ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
Guid uuidi = Guid.NewGuid();
string uuid1 = uuidi.ToString();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new ChannelOptions { ChannelId = uuid1 });
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ChannelOptions options1;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ChannelOptions options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        options1 = options;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var re = options1.ChannelId;
        return View();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution and code example - the result is exactly what I was looking to achieve.

Comment: If you feel my answer has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks how face the same issue could find the solution more easily. Thank you.